# What happens when I assign a number larger than INT_MAX to an int?

Tags: c++

Suppose I assign an eleven digits number to an int, what will happen? I played around with it a little bit and I know it's giving me some other numbers within the int range. How is this new number created?

Comment: Try converting the input and output values to binary or hex. That should give you a good idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *implementation-defined* behaviour. This means that your compiler must provide documentation saying what happens in this scenario.

So, consult that documentation to get your answer.

A common way that implementations define it is to truncate the input integer to the number of bits of `int` (after reinterpreting unsigned as signed if necessary).

C++14 Standard references: [expr.ass]/3, [conv.integral]/3

Comment: I'm curious, where specifically does it say this for (signed) integral *assignment* rather than just initialization? I know this behaviour can be found in Integral Conversions, but I can't find where it says those are applied for assignment.

Comment: Aha! [conv]/4 and [conv]/6.

Comment: @chris see [expr.ass]/3 which says that assignment causes implicit conversion to the type of the left operand (for non-class types)

Comment: Wow, I read through that like three times and didn't notice. I knew there was still that missing piece left. Thanks for filling it in.

Answer (score 2):

In C++20, this behavior will still be *implementation-defined*<sup>1</sup> but the requirements are much stronger than before. This is a side-consequence of the requirement to use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation for signed integer types coming in C++20.

This kind of conversion is specified by [[conv.integral]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral):

> 1. A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. [...]
> 2. [...]
> 3. Otherwise, the result is the unique value of the destination type that is congruent to the source integer modulo 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is the width of the destination type.
> 4. [...]

This behaviour is the same as truncating the representation of the number to the width of the integer type you are assigning to, e.g.:

```
int32_t u = 0x6881736df7939752;
```

...will kept the 32 right-most bits, i.e., `0xf7939752`, and "copy" these bits to `u`. In two's complement, this corresponds to `-141322414`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> This will still be implementation-defined because the size of `int` is implementation-defined. If you assign to, e.g., `int32_t`, then the behaviour is fully defined.</sub>

---

Prior to C++20, there were two different rules for unsigned and signed types:

> 1. A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. [...]
> 2. If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [...]
> 3. If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

`INT_MAX` on a 32 bit system is 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup> − 1), `UINT_MAX` is 4,294,967,295 (2<sup>32</sup> − 1).

```
int thing = 21474836470;
```

What happens is implementation-defined, it's up to the compiler. Mine appears to truncate the higher bits. 21474836470 is 0x4fffffff6,

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'int' changes
  value from 21474836470 to -10 [-Wconstant-conversion]
int thing = 21474836470;
```

Comment: It's *implementation-defined*; this is different to *unspecified* in that the compiler must document the behaviour.

Comment: @M.M I took the liberty to clean up the answer a little bit.