# Form minimum number from the given sequence of I's and D's

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, vector

Given a sequence consisting of 'I' and 'D' where 'I' denotes increasing sequence and 'D' denotes the descreasing sequence. Write a program that decodes the given sequence to construct minimum number without repeated digits.
The digits should start from 1 i.e. there should be no zeroes.

```
   Input: D        Output: 21
   Input: I        Output: 12
   Input: DD       Output: 321
   Input: II       Output: 123
   Input: DIDI     Output: 21435
   Input: IIDDD    Output: 126543
   Input: DDIDDIID Output: 321654798
```

My python code works. I translated it into C++ but the C++ version doesn't work. I don't understand why.

Python code (Works):

```
s = input()
ans = [1]
count = 0
for i in s:
    if i == 'I':
        count = 0
        k = len(ans)
        ans.append(k + 1)
    else:
        count += 1
        tmp = ans[-1]
        for i in range(-1, -1 - count, -1):
            ans[i] += 1
        ans.append(tmp)
for i in ans:
    print(i, end = "")
```

C++ code (Doesn't work i.e. doesn't give the correct output)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> digits(string s){
    vector<int> ans = {1};
    int count = 0;
    for (char const &c : s){
        if (c == 'I'){
            count = 0;
            int k = ans.size();
            ans.push_back(k + 1);
        }
        else{
            count ++;
            int tmp = ans.back();
            for (int i = ans.size() - 1; i > ans.size() - 1 - count; i--){
                ans[i] += 1;
            }
            ans.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
   return ans; 
}

int main(){
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    vector<int> ans = digits(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++){
        cout << ans[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Eg - When I input DD in the C++ code, it gives 111, but it should output 321.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It doesn't give the correct output @ChrisMM

Comment: Don't add "edit" or "update" to your question. Just make the question complete. We can see the edit history if we need to know how it changed.

Comment: Why is `D` not `10`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist D, we start from 1. We don't use zero. That's a constraint.

Comment: Makes sense. So you are guaranteed a sequence of no more than 8 letters?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yes

Comment: Have you tried debugging the C++, using a debugger or print statements?

Comment: You should add some print statements to your code to monitor the values of your variables, or use a debugger! Your for loop is never entered because `ans.size() - 1 - count` leads to an integer underflow as `ans.size()` returns an `std::size_t` which is an unsigned integer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'd tried printing. I didn't yet use a debugger though (I'm just a beginner, so I'm learning, my bad).

Comment: @Justanotherperson On an unrelated note, [don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ans.size()` in C++ returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned (either 32-bit or 64-bit depending on your configuration). You can simply cast `ans.size()` to an `int` to fix your issue, like so:

```
for ( int i = static_cast<int>(ans.size()) - 1; i > static_cast<int>(ans.size()) - 1 - count; i-- )
```

Using a debugger, you could check that you never actually got into the `for-loop`'s body, for your input.

As NotAProgrammer notes, unsigned-to-signed conversion may be implementation defined, but this should work in most (all?) cases for your examples.
From `[conv.integral]/3`:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type;
> otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Comment: Just a note that casting unsigned to signed is implementation-defined.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer can you elaborate that a bit with an example? I didn't understand.

Comment: @Justanotherperson, see my edit with the quote from the C++ standard.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer Only for values outside the range of the unsigned type. It seems unlikely `ans.size()` will be larger than the maximum value of `int`, especially assuming that `int` is at least 32-bit (as it probably is).

Comment: @ArthurTacca It's true that it is unlikely to lead to a problem in this case, but you know what they about "assume". Edit: Isn't it true for values outside the range of the signed type, rather than the unsigned type?

Comment: @NotAProgrammer. I assume that they say it's a good idea :)

Comment: @NotAProgrammer are there specific cases where we need to convert 'unsigned int' into 'int' even if the value is very low ?

Comment: @NotAProgrammer Oops, you're right about that edit. But I am prepared to risk the consequences of my assumption when violating it would require the user to manually enter a string more than 2 billion characters long, and the code appears to assume the string is less than 10 characters!

Comment: @Justanotherperson [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528886/3672674) may shed some more light on this (and the thread as well). But no, I can't think of a time when using small numbers non-negative numbers will lead to a problem. Of course in your case you tried to assign -1 to an unsigned int which lead to a problem.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer where is -1 assigned to an unsigned int?

Comment: @Justanotherperson What is the result of `ans.size() - 1 - count` on the first time the condition is checked?

Comment: @NotAProgrammer oops, my bad.